# Calculate percentage of matching words in a string of words

Tags: php, regex, string, percentage

I have a string with a bunch of words with a space delimiter that comes from my database and another similar string with words from user input.

```
$usrKeywords = 'test1 test4 test2'; //$_POST['keywords']

$dbKeywords  = 'test1 test2 test3 test4 test5'; //from the DB
```

How can I check the percentage of how many user keywords match the database keywords?

So for the above case it would be 60%.

I know I would have to know how many words there are in total, and then check how many matching user keywords are contained in the db keywords string and then do like `3 / 5 * 100` to get the percentage (for the above example).

But code wise I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to compute this percentage:

```
$usrKeywords = 'test1 test4 test2'; //$_POST['keywords']
$dbKeywords  = 'test1 test2 test3 test4 test5'; //from the DB

$arr1 = explode(' ', $usrKeywords);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $dbKeywords);

$aint = array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);

print_r($aint);
echo "percentage = " . (count($aint) * 100 / count($arr2)); // 60
```

Comment: what a sneaky solution to use array intersect here. Great!

Comment: Thanks @zx81 glad you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$usrKeywords = 'test1 test4 test2'; //$_POST['keywords']
$dbKeywords  = 'test1 test2 test3 test4 test5';

$user_keywords_unique = array_unique(explode(' ', $usrKeywords));
$db_keywords_unique = array_unique(explode(' ', $dbKeywords));
$matches = array_intersect($user_keywords_unique, $db_keywords_unique);
$percentage = 100*count($matches)/count($user_keywords_unique);
echo $percentage.'% of the user keywords exist in the database';
```